# SQL One to Many column association rows

Tags: mysql, one-to-many

Given the table below I want to select the rows for which the same 'CODE' is associated with multiple 'SUB_CODE'.

```
+------+------------+-------------+
| DIV  |    CODE    |  SUB_CODE   |
+------+------------+-------------+
| 11   | 1000       | 1212        |
| 11   | 1000       | 1213        |
| 11   | 1000       | 3434        |
| 11   | 1000       | 1000        |
| 11   | 1000       | 3000        |
| 11   | 3000       | 1213        |
| 11   | 2000       | 1212        |
| 20   | 1500       | 5656        |
| 20   | 1500       | 1213        |
+------+------------+-------------+
```

For the above table the result should be

```
+------+------------+-------------+
| DIV  |    CODE    |  SUB_CODE   |
+------+------------+-------------+
| 11   | 1000       | 1212        |
| 11   | 1000       | 1213        |
| 11   | 1000       | 3434        |
| 11   | 1000       | 1000        |
| 11   | 1000       | 3000        |
| 11   | 1500       | 5656        |
| 11   | 1500       | 1213        |
+------+------------+-------------+
```

This is what I tried, how ever my results fails.

```
Select CODE from TABLE_NAME where (count(SUB_CODE) > 1);
```

Comment: what result did you get?

Comment: I got an error 'Aggregates NOT allowed in where clause' .

Answer (score 1):

First fetch the `CODE`s for which multiple `SUB_CODE`s exists; then project the table columns filtering using the above results as a nested query:

```
select * from TABLE_NAME where CODE in 
    (select CODE from TABLE_NAME group by CODE having count(SUB_CODE) > 1);
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d91f/3/0

Comment: @sql_learner Welcome to stackoverflow; if you found the answer helpful, please mark it as accepted. The community behind this site provides an awesome learning place, check how to get the most if it here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:

```
Select `DIV`, `CODE`, `SUB_CODE` from TABLE_NAME GROUP BY `SUB_CODE`
```